# find all 256 cases of 2 numbers in array of 8 length

Tags: c, algorithm

How can I find all combination of 2 numbers `{0,1}` in array of 8 length in c,
example

```
   arr[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
   arr[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}
   arr[]={0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1}
an so on
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Most cases you'd be better off leaving it as an number and doing bitwise operations on that rather than on an array.

Comment: When there are just 2 options, they're digital bits. They're on or they're not. How many bits does a byte have? 8. What is 2^8? 256. Every value that a byte can have represents one of those combinations. You yourself told us 256 in your question, so what is there you're trying to find out that you haven't already told us. It seems to me you already have the answer. :confused:

Comment: To do a comparison of arr1 with this array and calculate how many times is equal

Comment: @enhzflep i want to generate those cases to make a counter of how many time it's eqaul

Comment: Your "example" really doesn't make sense. What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate all combinations fairly easily using a recursive procedure:

```
arr = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

Generate(position)
   if position > 8 then
       print arr
   else
       arr[position] = 0
       Generate(position+1)
       arr[position] = 1
       Generate(position+1)

Generate(1)
```

This will go down 8 levels in the call stack and then print the array [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Then it will return to the 7th level, and go down again, printing [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]. It will repeat this process, toggling each of the higher-order bits in turn until all 256 possibilities are generated. Instead of printing the arrays, you could save the arrays as you go.

Another possibility is to just create the 256 8-bit arrays and use an iterative procedure to toggle the elements in such a way as to guarantee you cover all your bases. An example with 4-bit strings:

```
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0  => toggle bits in 4th position => 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0     in blocks of size 1            0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 1


0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1  => toggle bits in 3rd position => 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0     in blocks of size 2            0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 1 1


0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1  => toggle bits in 2nd position => 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0     in blocks of size 4            0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1                                    0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0                                    0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1                                    0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0                                    0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1                                    0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0                                    0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1                                    0 1 0 1
0 0 1 0                                    0 1 1 0
0 0 1 1                                    0 1 1 1


0 0 0 0                                    0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1  => toggle bits in 1st position => 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0     in blocks of size 8            0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1                                    0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0                                    0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1                                    0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0                                    0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1                                    0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0                                    1 0 0 0
0 0 0 1                                    1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0                                    1 0 1 0
0 0 1 1                                    1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0                                    1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1                                    1 1 0 1
0 1 1 0                                    1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1                                    1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Great,thank's it work's